# Programmatically replace a variable value in script tag in html post build

Tags: angular, build, html-parsing

After building an Angular application, my requirement is to create a copy of index.html and change a variable in that.  How can that be done programmatically.  One option ofcourse is to do a string replace but is there any other way by parsing the html.
e.g. below is index.html with mode "Internal", i want to create another copy of it say "public.html" and replace the mode to `view = 'PUBLIC'` post build.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script type="application/javascript">
    var global = window;
    window.__VIEW__ = 'INTERNAL';
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root role="main">
  </app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) on HTML template files, or in this case, an embedded script.

```js
function renderHello() {
  var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
  var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {
    name: 'Luke'
  });
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = rendered;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="renderHello()">
  <div id="target">Loading...</div>
  <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    Hello {{ name }}!
  </script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/mustache@latest"></script>
</body>

</html>
```